# Upload data to openstreetmap via javascript

Tags: openstreetmap

Is there a way to upload data (for example points/routes) to openstreetmap via javascript?
I develop a mobile application, where the users could upload some kinds of data to openstreetmap. I would like to create my own editor for this (to be able to restrict the kind of data uploaded, and to provide a user friendly mobile solution).

Can it be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, why not? The [OpenStreetMap API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_v0.6) is based on simple HTTP requests. First you need to [authenticate](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_v0.6#URL_.2B_authentication) yourself using an user name and password or via OAuth. Then you can [upload](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_v0.6#Create:_PUT_.2Fapi.2F0.6.2Fchangeset.2Fcreate) new [changesets](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Changeset).

Note that each of your users will need an OSM account in order to upload data.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense :)

Do you think is there a way for the users not having to have an OSM account? (for example they send the data to my web server, and from my web server I upload the data to OSM). Because I would not want to make my users life harder by expecting them to create an OSM account in addition to my own application account.

Comment: No, having a single account for multiple users is strongly discouraged. Without separate accounts there will be problems when having to resolve copyright issues. Additionally OSM is a community project where contributors must be able to talk directly to other contributors in order to discuss local decisions, to explain and resolve beginner mistakes and so on. It also makes vandalism harder to revert. Please don't do this.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I see the point. I think I'm gonna change my current authentication to openstreetmap's OAuth, so the users don't need to create 2 different accounts.